# Understanding oauth external login authentication flow in ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, oauth, authorization, asp.net-identity-3

I'm implementing Identity in ASP.NET Core 3 and having a bit of a problem understanding the flow of external login authentication, as are my users.

Things start clearly enough:

[image: External login]

As expected I'm prompted to pick a Google identity:

[image: Google login dialog]

Now at this point I'd expect to see a dialog such as the following, asking for permission to grant my app access to various pieces of the Google identity:

[image: Grant access dialog]

But that dialog never happens.

What does happen next is:

[image: Confirm email address]

The above process step seems completely non-standard to any oauth flow I've ever seen.  I've already given it which Google identity I'm using; the email address is unambigious.  So this dialog seems extraneous and just confuses my users.  **Is there a reason for this step that I am not understanding?**

...And back to the permission dialog above that I would have expected to get there, this never occurs.  **Why is the app able to accept a Google login *without* granting access via that dialog?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is the app able to accept a Google login without granting access via that dialog?

That seems Google will automatically grant OpenID Connect Scopes(`openid profile email`) after creating application . You can verify the scopes in console -->OAuth consent screen :

[image]

But if you want to also require additional sensitive scopes , you still need to grant permission dynamically during authentication :

```
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify");
    options.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic");
    options.ClientId = "xxxx";
    options.ClientSecret = "xxxx";
});
```

> Is there a reason for this step that I am not understanding?

That is because you enable the ASP.NET Core Identity. In asp.net core identity ,for external login ,after authentication , identity will help create a local user associated with external login user .After [scaffolding Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) , you could check the `ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs` file inside `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account` folder . In function `OnGetCallbackAsync` you will find identity will check the external login user information and confirm a local user is associated with external user , if yes , sign in user ; If no, it will redirect user to another page to ask the user to create an account in local database .

If you don't need that feature , just remove asp.net core identity or customize `OnGetCallbackAsync` function to skip the process .

Comment: you said: "In function OnGetCallbackAsync you will find identity will check the external login user information and confirm a local user is associated with external user , if yes , sign in user ; If no, it will redirect user to another page to ask the user to create an account in local database . If you don't need that feature , just remove asp.net core identity or customize OnGetCallbackAsync function to skip the process ."  Do you mean that it is NOT necessarily for external login users to have a local account?  They can access my site via asp.net core identity w/o local account?

Comment: `Do you mean that it is NOT necessarily for external login users to have a local account?` That depends on your requirement . `They can access my site via asp.net core identity w/o local account?` No , that is just a local account associate with external user , you still need to login using external identity provider .